# Как из txt преобразовать в dict? [PYTHON]

Tags: dict

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из текста(файла) сверху сделать словарь. Что бы читало как ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код следует вставлять текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читается файл по строкам, удаляя символ переноса строки и игнорируя запятые в конце. При помощи `split` строка делится на ключ/значение, для которых в свою очередь `strip` убирает лишние пробелы и кавычки.

```
dict = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline().rstrip()[:-1]
        if not line:
            break
        key, value = (i.strip('\'\" ') for i in line.split(":"))
        dict[key] = value
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

то же самое через  `csv`:

```
import csv
with open(file_path, newline='') as file:  # filepath - путь к файлу
    items = csv.reader(file, delimiter=': ')
    d = {k:v for k,v in items}
```